# Raven DB Hierarchy issue

Tags: ravendb

I've been through a few example but can't get this to work:

The end goal is to get the parent and child name together split by a hyphen.

I have an index:

```
public class Category_Hierarchy : AbstractIndexCreationTask<CategoryDocument>
{
    public Category_Hierarchy()
    {
        Map = categories => from cat in categories
            from parent in Recurse(cat, c => LoadDocument<CategoryDocument>("CategoryDocuments/" + c.ParentId))
            select new
            {
                Id = cat.Id,
                Name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", cat.Name, parent.Name)
            };
    }
}
```

I'm querying it like:

```
 List<Category_Hierarchy> cats = session.Query<Category_Hierarchy>().ToList();
```

I currently store the parent Id so append the document name 'CategoryDocments/' to the LoadDocument not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: What are you trying to do?
LoadDocument in index is expensive, and you can avoid it in many cases.

Comment: Looks like you have the potential risk of circular recursion here. Since it seems that the parent categories and child categories are of the same type and are "linked" by parentId. So you could have document A be the parent of document B, and document B be the parent of document A.

Not sure if it would be better to have a CategoryParentDocument and CategoryChildDocument and join them? (Looking at Ayende for this one...)